# What is the largest number of solutions to an instance of Stable Marriage?

Tags: algorithm, stable-marriage

Every Stable Marriage problem has at least one solution. However, how to know the largest number of solutions to a stable marriage problem? The Gale-Shapley algorithm can only find one man-optimal solution. If we use woman-optimal method to run Gale-Shapley, there may be another solution. Are there at most two solutions to an instance of stable marriage, or can Gale-Shapley only find two solutions, and there are some other solutions beyond them?

Comment: There definitely can be more than two solutions.  The [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_marriage_problem) gives an example with three solutions.

Comment: I would be more than a little surprised if this weren't a #P-complete problem.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Your suspicion is correct: [The Complexity of Counting Stable Marriages](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/0215048), SIAM J. Comput., 15(3), 655–667

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Computer Science (which has its own site), not programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/5619/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-stable-marriages-for-an-instance-of-the-stable-mar where it is discussed that an exponential worst-case lower bound of Omega(2.28^n) stable marriages is given for all n for n men/women (by giving a family of examples where this many stable marriages are possible).